# Git shell function (for aliasing) worked in bash with tab complete but not working in Zsh

Tags: git, zsh, alias

The alias I've used with success in bash but no longer works in Zsh looks like this

In `.zshrc` (previously `.bashrc`)

```
# custom git completions 
_git_a ()
{
    _git_add
}
_git_b ()
{
    _git_branch
}
_git_c ()
{
    _git_commit
}
_git_co () 
{
    _git_checkout 
}
.
.
.

# git alias function
g ()
{
    arg1=$1
    shift
    case "$arg1" in
        a)
            eval git add $@;;
        b)
            eval git branch $@;;
        c)
            eval git commit -m \"$1\";;
        co)
            eval git checkout $@;;
        .
        .
        .
        *)
            eval git $arg1 $@;;
    esac
}

zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.git-completions-mingit.bash
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -u
source ~/.mingit.sh
compdef g='git'
```

It used to be the case (in bash) that typing something within the alias such as

```
g co<TAB><TAB>
```

would result in the same behavior as

```
git checkout<TAB><TAB>
```

but now (in Zsh) the result is that `g co<TAB><TAB>` cycles through folders and files in the directory.  Is there a way to get the tab completion on `g co` or other `g` commands to work the same as `git ...` when it comes to tab completion?

Comment: At the very least, you don't need `eval` for this. `case $arg1 in a) git add $@;; ...` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by following the instructions in `git-completion.zsh` (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh):

```
# For example, create a directory '~/.zsh/', copy this file to '~/.zsh/_git',
# and then add the following to your ~/.zshrc file:
#
#  fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)
#
# You need git's bash completion script installed. By default bash-completion's
# location will be used (e.g. pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion).
```